# FAILED: HiveAuthzPluginException Error getting permissions for hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am trying to insert data into hive table from a file in hdfs directory by the query:

```
$ jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/xyz/stdfiles/testtbl.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE testdb.testtbl;
```

But the query failed resulting:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED:
>   HiveAuthzPluginException Error getting permissions for
>   hdfs://localhost:9000/user/xyz/stdfiles/testtbl.txt: null
>   (state=42000,code=40000)

I have tried giving permissions by the following command which gives no error:

```
$ hdfs dfs -chown -R stdfiles /user/xyz/stdfiles
$ hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /user/xyz/stdfiles/testtbl.txt
```

Checked:

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/xyz/stdfiles
19/05/22 09:15:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 1 items
-rwxrwxrwx 1 stdfiles supergroup 6 2019-05-22 08:45 /user/xyz/stdfiles/testtbl.txt
```

Inserting data successfully is by desired output

Answer (score 0):

Add following properties in hadoop configuration file core-site.xml worked for me :)

```
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.niazullah.hosts</name>
     <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.niazullah.groups</name>
     <value>*</value>
</property>
```

---

Also check for user access hdfs:

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls /user
```

Output:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - main supergroup          0 2019-05-22 13:22 /user/test
```

Where "main" is the user change it do the hive user

Comment: HELP! Now it fails here:

`FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path ''/user/xyz/stdfiles/abc.txt'': No files matching path file:/user/xyz/stdfiles/abc.txt`